# Dialog on web version of Outlook does not send messages between parent and child

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I have an add-in that opens a dialog box using `Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync()` with `displayInIframe: true`

I compose an email and open the add-in. Using the add-in I select the files I wish to attach to the email. On the desktop Outlook app this works perfectly.

On the web version nothing happens. I can't see any communication between the dialog and host page when using `Office.context.ui.messageParent()` or `Office.Dialog.messageChild()`

The frontend in the dialog sends a message with the file blob to the parent function in the functionfile. The functionfile should then call `addFileAttachmentFromBase64Async()` when it receives this message but on the web version I can't see any evidence of this.

I've read it could be to the urls in the  in the manifest.xml. Here is ours:

```
<AppDomains>
    <AppDomain>https://outlook.office.com</AppDomain>
    <AppDomain>https://outlook.live.com</AppDomain>
    <AppDomain>https://localhost:44312</AppDomain>
    <AppDomain>https://*.{company}.cloud</AppDomain>
    <AppDomain>https://localhost:3001</AppDomain>
</AppDomains>
```

And here is the simplified section of code that opens the dialog:

```
Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync(url, { height: 60, width: 60, displayInIframe: true }, asyncResult => {
        if (handleError(asyncResult)) return;

        dialog = asyncResult.value;

        dialog.addEventHandler(Office.EventType.DialogMessageReceived, processMessage);

        const promises = [];

        {working business logic}

        Promise.all(promises).then(values => {
            {working business logic}

            event.completed();
        });
    });
```

Other issues we have in the web version that might be releavent:

- The 'X' close button in the top right of the dialog box does not work. Neither will calls to `Office.context.ui.closeContainer()` or `Office.Dialog.close()`
- If we set `displayInIframe: false` then the add-in will immediately close itself upon opening unless we throttle our internet connect. But even when throttling the attaching email process does not work. If I remove the `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1.1/hosted/office.js" crossorigin></script>`  script in the .html then it no longer crashes (but naturally the app needs that)

I have tested this on both Edge and Chrome and they both have this issue. I have not tested on any other browsers

Again, the app works correctly and as expected on the Outlook desktop app. Any help or suggests are appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Could you also specify what web browser did you use for testing?

Comment: I have tested this on both Edge and Chrome and they both have this issue. I have not tested on any other browsers. I've add this info the the post as well.

Comment: I don't see any code for handling cases with X close button, where do you subscribe to such events in the code?

Comment: I haven't subscribed to any events related to the close button. On the desktop app version the close button just worked without having to code anything. I assumed it would be the same for the web side? Do I have to subscribe to an event and handle the closing via code?

Comment: I've looked at the DialogEventReceived and added it into the `dialog.addEventHandler()` in the simplified code example in my post which should trigger on close. As far as I can see this event isn't being triggered at all when I click close or when I call the close dialog function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the `event.completed()` call from the callback.